# Swift free hand drawing

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying this code to free hand drawing in UIImageView.

The problem in ( carves ).

```
class DrawingImageView: UIImageView {
    var points: [CGPoint]?
    var path: UIBezierPath?
    var pathLayer: CAShapeLayer!    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        pathLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        pathLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        pathLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.clear.withAlphaComponent(0.5).cgColor
        pathLayer.lineWidth = 15
        pathLayer.lineJoin =  .round 
        pathLayer.lineCap =  .round 
        pathLayer.allowsEdgeAntialiasing = true
        pathLayer.allowsGroupOpacity = true
        pathLayer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        pathLayer.shadowOpacity = 1
        pathLayer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
        pathLayer.shadowRadius = 5
        self.layer.addSublayer(pathLayer)

        if let touch = touches.first {
            points = [touch.location(in: self)]
        }
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if let touch = touches.first {
            if let coalescedTouches = event?.coalescedTouches(for: touch) {
                points? += coalescedTouches.map { $0.location(in: self) }
            } else {
                points?.append(touch.location(in: self))
            }

            if let predictedTouches = event?.predictedTouches(for: touch) {
                let predictedPoints = predictedTouches.map { $0.location(in: self) }
                pathLayer.path = UIBezierPath.interpolateHermiteFor(points: points! + predictedPoints, closed: false).cgPath
            } else {
                pathLayer.path = UIBezierPath.interpolateHermiteFor(points: points!, closed: false).cgPath
            }
        }
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        pathLayer.path = UIBezierPath.interpolateHermiteFor(points: points!, closed: false).cgPath
        points?.removeAll()
    }
}
```

I don't know what the problem is ( carve ).

It's not rounded and I use:

```
pathLayer.lineJoin =  .round 
pathLayer.lineCap =  .round
```

The result is attached in image:

[image: attached]